# How to set the background image behind the image using css

Tags: css

I am trying to set the background image which is in svg format behind the image which is in png format.
The cloud image is my first image which I want to put behind the actual image.
I want to fit the cloud image behind the actual image.
How can I do this using css?

I am getting this as a result as shown in image

[image]

This is a expected output result image

[image: expected output image]

```css
.automata-cloud {
  background-image: url('../../../assets/images/cloud_001.svg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: no-repeat;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
}

.automated_intelligence {
  padding: 0 0 80px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xl-7 col-md-6 col-xs-12 banner-image">
  <img class="automated_intelligence_img automata-cloud" src="assets/images/homepage_ban.png">
</div>
```

Comment: a background is always *behind*

Comment: put the background on the div containing the image.  If this causes issues as the div is too wide, then wrap your image in a span that is inline-block and put the background on that.  Also please note that z-index only works on positioned elements

Comment: I believe you meant to put `banner-image` instead of `automata-cloud` in the CSS. It wouldn't make much sense to put a `background-image` for an image.

Comment: If anything is not working, then please give us a proper problem description, and a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the background image to the div not to the image itself. Instead do something like this.

```
.banner-image{
  background-image: url('../../../assets/images/cloud_001.svg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: no-repeat; 
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100%;
}
.automated_intelligence_img{
  padding: 0 0 80px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: I think case it is not getting whole cloud image covered as shown in the expected image screenshot